# Json-Schema evolution: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema

Tags: jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to do a very basic json-schema evolution:
From this:

```
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/myURI.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "myField1": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  "required": ["myField1"],
  "type": "object"
}
```

To this new version, which adds another field "myField2", but is not required.

```
  "$id": "http://example.com/myURI.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "myField1": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "myField2": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "myField1"
  ],
  "type": "object"
}
```

However I have always in schema registry UI:

> Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema

Am I missing something?

Comment: You haven't said which compatibility mode your subject is configured for. Default is BACKWARD, in which case James' answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a default value for the new field.  See the confluent documentation https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html.  This maintains BACKWARD compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The default rules for JSON schema compatibility implemented in Confluent's Schema Registry don't allow optional properties to be added or removed, if you want full compatibility, without jumping through some pretty weird hoops.

See Creek's [post on why this is](https://www.creekservice.org/articles/2024/01/08/json-schema-evolution-part-1.html), this goes into this in some detail, plus links to other posts with more details, and the second post in the series explains how to implement more useful compatibility checks.